# What are the basic steps to RGB to HSV conversion in mathematical steps?

Tags: java, math

i.e before code. What steps do you take to do this conversion? Similar with texture, how to you calculate the texture of an image? Any idea's or links to decent papers or websites would be really appreciated.

I will eventually have to code this in a java based content based image retrieval tool.

Comment: Answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556341/rgb-to-hsv-color-conversion-algorithm)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is explicitly not about programming.

Comment: We'll it infact is about programming as I will use the math behind it to write my code. Believe it or not, sometimes planning and background research is required in computing. Next time I will just post asking for someone to write the code for me, how does that sound? No-one likes a stickler @NicoSchertler .

Comment: Thank you for your help @kdbanman

Comment: I could have voted to close for any other reason. The question is just not a good fit for SO. If you're researching, you must have been stumbled upon plenty of material. In the end, it's just simple coordinate transformation. So the reasons are: Not about programming. No visible effort. Several duplicates exist. Unclear, what you're actually asking.

Comment: Several duplicates exist but it is unclear what I am asking, is that what you are saying? if it is unclear, how are you fit to know duplicates exist? If it is unclear, how are you aware it is just a simple coordinate transformation? Mathematics plays a sizeable role in programming @NicoSchertler someone of your vast, deep and esteemed knowledge should be aware of that. You are a stickler my friend.

Comment: At the end of the day, I am a student on this website seeking guidance and if you are not going to help me you should focus your energy somewhere where it would be appreciated. @NicoSchertler

Comment: What I meant is the following: The transformation from RGB to HSV is a well-known method (which you can read e.g. on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)). And there exist questions about how to program this transformation. Given this method, I have no clue what you want to know about it. If it is about how to derive this method, the answer will soon become open-ended. Maybe, the programming relatedness wasn't the best close reason after all. But I can still not answer this question, as I don't know what you're asking.